# Why do all mouse-events I input in Drracket become Numbers?

Tags: lisp, mouseevent, racket, interactive

I'm trying to build an drawing-application in Drracket (using language is BSL). The object I want to achieve is

1. when mouse-event is "button-down", start drawing a line
2. when mouse-event is "drag", move the current line's end point
3. when mouse-event is "button-up", add the current line to the canvas.
   So I wrote these code below

```
    (define (handle-mouse appstate mouse-event x-mouse y-mouse)
  (cond
    [(string=? mouse-event "button-down") (add-line (AppState-image appstate) x-mouse y-mouse x-mouse y-mouse "red")]
    [(string=? mouse-event "drag") (move-end appstate x-mouse y-mouse)]
    [(string=? mouse-event "button-up") (add-line-to-canvas appstate)]
    [else appstate]))
```

But when I move the mouse into the canvas, there is an error like this

```
string=?: expects a string, given 319
```

It means the input mouse-event is a number, so I change the code to this

```
(define (handle-mouse appstate mouse-event x-mouse y-mouse)
  (cond
    [(string? mouse-event) (cond
                                             [(string=? mouse-event "button-down") (add-line (AppState-image appstate) x-mouse y-mouse x-mouse y-mouse "red")]
                                             [(string=? mouse-event "drag") (move-end appstate x-mouse y-mouse)]
                                             [(string=? mouse-event "button-up") (add-line-to-canvas appstate)])]
    [else appstate]))
```

So there are no more errors, but the program doesn't respond to mouse events either. I think it's because of some errors that turns all mouse-events to Numbers. But I can't figure it out. Could someone help? Thank you!

*AppState is the structure I defined to show the state of the app.

```
(define-struct AppState [image mbline boolean])
```

and mbline means "Maybe", a line is also a structure consisting of a start point and a end point

```
(define-struct Line [startpoint endpoint])
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the parameter order mixed up – the event string is the last parameter, so it should be

```
(define (handle-mouse appstate x-mouse y-mouse mouse-event)
```